# How to replace a character before and after a match

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I my file i have `<br>` tag. I want to replace any space before or after it using `_` underscore character

How can i do this using sed or awk or perl.

Eg:

`Note:` I am using `:` because spaces are getting ignored with ` (tick marks)

`:    <br>   :` to be replaced with `____<br>___`

`:      <br>   :` to be replaced with `______<br>___`

`:      <br>:` to be replaced with `______<br>`

`:<br>   :` to be replaced with `<br>___`

I tried

```
$ echo "test  test  <br>   test  test" | sed '/ *<br> */s/ /_/g' 
test__test__<br>___test__test
```

But i am expecting `test  test__<br>___test  test`

**I tried @philippe answer**.

Its working but i came up with another problem of spaces

I have tried

```
$ echo "for messages:<br>        # This" | perl -pe 's[(\s*<br>\s*)][$v=$1; $v =~ s/ /_/g; "$v"]ge'
for messages:<br>        # This
```

Why its not working.

If i delete the space and then manually insert the same spaces it works. What kind of spaces are those i dont know.

```
$ echo "for messages:<br>         # This" | perl -pe 's[(\s*<br>\s*)][$v=$1; $v =~ s/ /_/g; "$v"]ge'
for messages:<br>_________# This
```

Both the following sentenses look same but only one works. Can you tell me whats mysterious. You can copy paste in your terminal

```
"for messages:<br>        # This"  #NOT WORKIN
"for messages:<br>        # This"  #WORKING
```

I copy pasted in sublime text editor to see what type of space characters are they

So `\s*<br>\s*` is working only with one type of spaces.

[image]

Also for the case not working

```
$ echo "for messages:<br>        # This" | od -a
0000000   f   o   r  sp   m   e   s   s   a   g   e   s   :   <   b   r
0000020   >   B  sp  sp   B  sp  sp   B  sp  sp   B  sp  sp   #  sp   T
0000040   h   i   s  nl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl version:

```
echo "test  test  <br>   test  test" | perl -CSD -pe 's[\s*<br>\s*][$& =~ s/\s/_/gr]ge'
```

For the case which is not working, run this command and paster result :

```
echo "for messages:<br>        # This" | od -a
```

I have :

```
0000000   f   o   r  sp   m   e   s   s   a   g   e   s   :   <   b   r
0000020   >  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp  sp   #  sp   T   h   i   s  nl
```

Comment: I updated my question with your solution which is working. I am facing another problem of spaces. Can you go through it

Comment: I have updated my question with the output you asked. its different

Comment: I found that to be nbsp. I will replace nbsp with space and then i will use the answer. thank you

Comment: Tip: `$v=$1; $v =~ s/ /_/g; "$v"` can be written as `$1 =~ s/ /_/gr`

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi, Use `-CSD` (`perl -CSD -pe'...'`) This will decode the input and encode the output so that `$_` actually contains a NBSP, so that `\s` matches it

Comment: @ikegami nice improvement ! Would you mind giving an example of `perl -CSD ...` processing NBSP ?

Comment: @ikegami thanks again for the explanation ! Last question : why `perl -CSD -e'print chr(0xA0)'` transformed `0xa0` to `0xc2 0xa0` ?

Comment: That's the UTF-8 encoding of U+00A0 NBSP. Pretend I used `print "\N{NBSP}"` if that helps